# Filemaker Insert PDF script error [3] command is unavailable

Tags: pdf, scripting, containers, filemaker

In my Filemaker (version 14.0.4 advanced) application, I am trying to provide flexibilty to allow user to import a picture, file or PDF into a container field on portal record so it can either be viewed or downloaded from another user.  I am trying to use the "Insert PDF" script but through the debugger I get the following indicator:

Last error: [3] Command is unavailable (for example, wrong operating system or mode)

This does work with the Insert Picture and Insert File script and I'm on Windows 7.

One thing I notice when I actually insert a PDF using the Insert Picture script is that I can actually view the PDF in my popover button with a container field but when running the Insert Picture script, it defaults to the Files of Type as "All Pictures" instead of "All Files" which could be misleading for users, so if there's any way to default to "All Files" this way then I may accept this as an alternative method or perhaps a way to select the file and save path and file name as a variable so I can pre-determine which method to use appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "Insert PDF" script step only works if the container field is set to "Interactive Content (PDF, MP3,etc)" in Data tab on the inspector.

"All Files" is only available on "Insert File", it also has an option display content if possible. Try using this step.

Comment: Hmmm, when using the Insert File script and changing both container and calculation of same container to "Interactive Content" I am somehow still seeing the PDF icon with the option when left clicking to Insert Picture, Insert File or Export Field Contents, not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: The behaviour does not change, if the container field is on a portal row. You need to look closely at your script. Another thing, how do you generate your PDFs? FileMaker might not be able to recognise them unless you specify explicitly.

Comment: These PDFs I'm testing with were created as a print file from an external application that's at least viewable through Adobe Reader DC.

Comment: As far as I remember, FileMaker uses their own PDF libraries., so seeing them with Adobe Reader does not mean anything.

Comment: After the import, check the file type and if it is PDF script export and import  back as PDF.